# Rails: pass content to partial as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, partial-views

I know that it is possible to pass parameters to partial views as strings.

But I want to pass large multiline contents as a parameter. In other words - I need to call partial in a construction similar to HTML tags:

```
<open_tag>
   contents
   contents
   contents
   contents
   contents
   contents
   contents
<close_tag>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass anything you want with the locals hash of render:

```
<%= render :partial => "my_partial" , :locals => { :my_var => "anything you want" } %>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this variant. My question is: how to specify my_var like a free-style multiline string without concatenating.

Comment: What is free-style multiline string? maybe you mean this: `:my_var => "contents\ncontents\ncontents\n"`

Comment: The problem here is the presence of "\n" instead of normal in-body CRLF symbols.

Comment: "Free-style multiline string"? Why not pass array of strings to the partial?